# What is the difference between list and 1-D array ? and what is the difference between series and dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

What is the difference between list and 1-D array ?  and what is the difference between series and dictionary ?

Answer (score -1):

list and dictionary are data types in python to hold data. The 1-D array is a data structure similar to a list that can contain any kind of data.
Both list or NumPy arrays can be one or multidimensional.
1-D means that every element in a list or in an array can be accessed by one index.
e.g.,:

```py
a = [1,2, 3]
# now if I want to access number 2 in the list I do it as
a[1]
# where as in 2-D, you need to pass to indexes in order to access an element:
b = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
# here if I want to access number 2 I need to pass two positional index:
b[0][1]
```

series are also 1-D arrays that hold any type of data, they are similar to tables. for example

```py
import pandas as pd

var = [1,2, 3]
sr = pd.Series(a)
print(sr)
---output---
0    1
1    7
2    2
```

2-D tables are referred to as dataframes. You can use dictionaries to make dataframes as follows:

```py
data = {
  "books": [20, 30, 40],
  "pages": [200, 300, 400]
}

# Convert the data into a 2-D table aka dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df) 

----output----
   books  pages
0     20    200
1     30    300
2     40    400
```